# Datasource exception when using gavlyukovskiy dependency to show query logging

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, datasource

dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.gavlyukovskiy</groupId>
            <artifactId>datasource-proxy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
 </dependency>
```

```
logging.level.net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener=debug
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'dataSource' is expected to be of type 'DynamicTenantAwareRoutingSource' but was actually of type 'com.github.gavlyukovskiy.boot.jdbc.decorator.DecoratedDataSource'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used `DataSource` interface instead of `DynamicTenantAwareRoutingSource` implementation of `DataSource` interface it worked well.